# How does the input for vertex shader work?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, sdl

In summary, I have the following vertices buffer:

```cpp
GLfloat _vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f };
```

I then set the vertices and call draw like this:

```
glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, _vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

My Vertex shader is as:

```c
#version 320 es
layout(location = 0) in vec2 vertPos;

out vec2 fragPos;
out float theLength;
void main()
{
    fragPos = vertPos;
    theLength = length(fragPos);
    gl_Position = vec4(vertPos.xy, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

And the fragment is:

```c
#version 320 es
precision mediump float;

in vec2 fragPos;
in float theLength;

out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0);
    float d = length(fragPos);

    fragColor = vec4(d, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

With the fragment like the one above I have the following image:
[image: I wasn't expecting this]

If I change the line `fragColor = vec4(d, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` to `fragColor = vec4(theLength, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` I got:

[image: This is OK.]

Why do I obtain different results? I was expecting to have a red square.
I'm using glsl shaders within SDL. Maybe SDL is implementing a Geometry Shader in the background?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

With `fragColor = vec4(theLength, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`, the length is only calculated on each vertex, then the length results for the vertices are interpolated.

Since all vertices have the same length (probably sqrt(2)), all interpolations between those values yield the same result.

In the original version, the length is calculated for each pixel (fragment) separately. This leads to having smaller values towards the center.

The important difference is which values get interpolated. In the first version, it's the position (which varies between vertices). Example for the first pixel row: fragPos.x is interpolated from -1 to 1 (with all values inbetween). fragPos.y is constant -1. When you then calculate the distance, you get different value for each fragment.

In the second version, it's the length which doesn't vary.

Comment: Thank you for the wuick answer. 
Howver on the first example. the color is the length of fragPos an input from vertexshader. It should be same.
Yes, you are correct length is sqrt(2).So the input for fragment shader can be different than the one I send from vertex shader?

Thank you

Comment: In the first version, the position is interpolated. Example for the first pixel row: fragPos.x is interpolated from -1 to 1 (with all values inbetween). fragPos.y is constant -1. When you then calculate the distance, you get different value for each fragment.

Answer (score 6):

By default the behavior is as follows (omiting work with depth buffer, stencil buffer other things unrelated here):

1. For every vertex, vertex shader evaluates `out` variables
2. For every face (triangle), the `out` variables for 3 its vertices are interpolated according to barycentric coordinates, this interpolation is separate for every fragment (pixel) belonging to the triangle
3. The fragment shader is executed for each such fragment, receiving interpolated values into `in` arguments

In the case of `fragPos`, it is different for every vertex, thus naturally you get interpolations with varying vectors, and length of those are proportional to the distance from the center, since your quad is in range -1 to 1

In the case of `length`, for every vertex the length evaluates to `sqrt(2)`, thus interpolation over those is constant for every fragment

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Vertex shader is invoked for each vertex - 3 invocations for a triangle.
Fragment shader is invoked for each fragment - invoked for each pixel(roughly).

Each uniform variable can have a interpolation qualifier - `smooth`, `flat`, or `noperspective` describing how to distribute the 3 values from the vertex shader to each invocation for the fragment shader.

If the qualifier is `flat`, then for each primitive there is a main vertex from which are the values of variables used for all fragments belonging to that primitive.

`smooth` would take the three values, for each vertex of the triangle, and interpolate between them. Try setting `theLength` to e.g. `.x` coordinate of the vertex and see for yourself.

It will never work with the pattern you want though as there is simply not enough information in the vertex shader.